# How do I push Real Names to iChat/Messages.app?

Tags: mac-osx-server, xmpp

I'm running OS X Mountain Lion Server with the Messages (iChat) service.  Whenever a user logs in to iChat, Messages.app, or any other jabber client the real names are not being populated for the users.  All of my users are required to go edit the users within their own client.  This has been tested in Spark for Windows, iChat, and Messages.app for OS X.

We have the user's info populated on OS X server; is there anyway to push this info through jabber so my users don't have to all enter first and last names for every person on chat?

We currently have about 25 users but are getting ready to expand the service to 100 users, hence the concern.